# ASP.NET FTP Download

Tags: asp.net, ftp

I have a need to push out a file package that includes a driver via my website for download. The only issue is it **cannot** be transferred in ASCII mode or else it becomes corrupt. I've looked at alternatives for FTP download but would rather not have an application that is created that can be downloaded just to transfer files. I'm looking into the possibility of creating an ASP.NET page that will use FTP for the download process.

I've seen a few examples but I also have a few questions:

1. How best to protect the login/password information instead of putting it in code? Can that be referenced from web.config?
2. Any possibility of showing download progress? Is AJAX my only option?
3. Ability to allow the user to select a download location on their local machine?

**EDIT**
Could I add a MIME type for ZIP and EXE files of *application/octet-stream* that would force a Binary download of the files?

Comment: So is this file package meant for client machines accessing your site through a browser?  Or is this some kind of service/tool to update an application you have installed on various machines?  Are the consuming machines controlled by you (or your company) or are they general public?

Comment: What I'm trying to stay away from is a package solution that I have to distribute out that does nothing more than download files. I would rather just have an ASP.NET page that they could visit to download a file and it would push the data down via FTP instead of HTTP.

Comment: ok.  So why can't you use "standard http download" for this?  Especially if your app is zipped there should be no reason it would be corrupted by the download.

Comment: One could assume this. But upon download, extraction and running the driver install spawns new processes. Due to file corruption one of the spawns of new processes fails every time which manages the actual driver management for the device. If downloaded via FTP Binary mode from the same exact location and handled the same way thereafter it works perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WebClient class.

```
using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
{
    ftpClient.DownloadFile("ftp://domain.org/file.txt", "file.txt");
}
```

For authenticated requests

```
using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
{
    ftpClient.DownloadFile("ftp://user:pass@domain.org/file.txt", "file.txt");
}
```

Comment: You can also use WebClient.OpenRead() and Response.OutputStream to tunnel the FTP data through HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Why FTP? You could create an HTTP Handler to push down the binaries. Here is more information on HTTP Handlers:
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm

Comment: Can you expand on your thoughts of using the HTTP Handler to "push down the binaries". How does this fix my issue of ASCII vs BINARY transfer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. With the Handler you can push either text or Binary.