# how can access files with virtual path of another server in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a photo gallery component that is checking the files inside folder using Physical path, after getting the list of files it's showing the list of files as a gallery. Now I have to separate my UI and File storage into different servers which means I can not get access to that folder with physical path in order to check if any files exist to show.
Please guide me how can I fix this issue when using "System.IO.Directory" in C#

```
        string path = dir + Aitem.ID.ToString();

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);

            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                string ff = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f);
                ...
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean that you try to access some server on different network that you can not map their path, neither have some kind of connection ? You must have a program running on the other server to replay to your request for the photo. This can be, web, ftp, what ever you make, and from there you need some other code locally to communicate and read the image.

Comment: i just have a virtual path from my file storage server,how can use this virtual path in my server?

Comment: Something like `"\\servername\drivec\file.png"` ? Or FTP account ?, if its ftp account, you need to use ftp client inside c#

Comment: something like (http://63.63.132.63/cms-netstorage),its the virtual path that i have from my file storage server i have to use this path in my UI server

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627794/asp-net-ftp-download

Comment: i visit this link but i think its not my answer i want to access all files and read them from this virtual path and then use it.

Comment: @SetarehMasompoor Did you test by absolute path of file ?

Comment: @aria no i don't test it.do you have any example or link that i follow it???Thanks

Comment: @SetarehMasompoor No unfortunately but absolute path like 'http://www.example.com/images/1.jpeg', Have you tried ?

Comment: @aria No i don't tried it but i i think its not work because i don't know is there any file in that folder or no?for check it i have to use 'system.Io.file exisit' and for this checking i have to use physical path.

Comment: @SetarehMasompoor So if you don't know there is file or no then how you want to check the path? if you want to check it by physical path then u must know that otherwise try something like 'www.example.com/images/...'